# Disabling button in bottom row in a wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with 4 columns, the first two of them are bound to an object.
The other two are button columns are made like this

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn  MaxWidth="100" Header="Delete">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Name="BtnDelete" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Id}" Content="Delete" Click="BtnDeleteEmployee_Click" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My Datagrid has CanUserAddRows="True" which always generates an empty row in the bottom of the grid.
However, I would like the two buttons on the bottom row to be disabled until the other rows have been filled. As it is now, I'm (of course) getting a nullreferenceexception when I click the button.

I guess a solution would be to bind the button's IsEnabled property to

```
id>0
```

But how to do this, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to bind the `IsEnabled` property to the Id property and use a ValueConverter to retun True or False based on your criteria.

A value converter could look  like this:

```
public class IdToEnabledConverter:IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return value != null && (int)value > 0;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

and you reference it in your resources section:

```
<Grid.Resources>
  <local:IdToEnabledConverter x:Key="IdToEnabledConverter"/>
</Grid.Resources>
```

And bind the `IsEnabled` property:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Id, Converter={StaticResource IdToEnabledConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a litte please? - I'm kinda new to WPF

Comment: I think it was a good idea, but whenever I try to edit a cell in the autogenerated row, I get an InvalidCastException. "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: That was my thought exactly. I did the following:     if (value == null)
                return false;
            return ((int)value) > 0;  But it did not work. I'm still getting the exception.

Comment: Well, first, is this the place you get the Exception? If so, what is the data type of your Id property? Further, set a breakpoint, examine the value and adjust your conversion/casting accordingly to cope with what's coming in.

Comment: datatype is int, the exception is thrown at return ((int)value) > 0;  The datagrids itemsource is a DataTable from an SqlDataAdapter. Can it be that the DataGrid generates a new row in the datatable with an ID that's one bigger than the last? then this will not work.

Comment: Again, do proper debugging. What's the value? If it's bigger than what an int can cope with, adjust your code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use style Trigger as below

```
 <Button.Style>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Id}" Value="{x:Null}">
                   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
              </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

This example hide the button completly when the value of `Id` is null. But same can be done with IsEnabled property to disable the button

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using MVVM pattern and Commands. If you use commands with button, it will automatically be disabled based on CanExecute() return value. So this is a place where you could check if id>0.

Some useful info about commands:
http://relentlessdevelopment.wordpress.com/2010/03/30/simplified-mvvm-commanding-with-delegatecommand/